# Codable NSManagedObject fail on decodeIfPresent Data type

Tags: swift, nsmanagedobject, codable

I obtain this error when i'm trying to decode this json:

```
[{
    "id": "76f22c25-cee7-4c7a-94fa-1fb85720f580",
    "purchaseDate": "2012-04-05T19:03:43Z",
    "title": "azare",

}, {
    "id": "9b4b9f7d-382f-4555-9eaa-97939b13633f",
    "purchaseDate": "2012-04-05T19:02:46Z",
    "title": "Chocolat",

}, {
    "id": "02a0aa06-2d0c-4ab9-aaaa-af7dee7b4845",
    "purchaseDate": "2012-09-24T17:39:52Z",
    "title": "Some thing",
}]
```

> Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Double,
>   Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [Foundation.(_JSONKey in
>   _12768CA107A31EF2DCE034FD75B541C9)(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: Optional(0)), MyApp.Purchase.CodingKeys.purchaseDate],
>   debugDescription: "Expected to decode Double but found a string/data
>   instead.", underlyingError: nil)): file
>   /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-900.0.69.2/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift,
>   line 181

```
My code:

//Purchase+CoreDataClass.swift
@objc(Purchase)
public class Purchase: NSManagedObject, Codable {

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case title
        case purchaseDate
    }

required convenience public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

var context : NSManagedObjectContext = MyAppCoreDataManager.sharedInstance.persistentContainer.viewContext
        guard let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Purchase", in: context!) else { fatalError() }

        self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context!)
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        self.title = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .title)
        self.id = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .id)
        self.purchaseDate = try! container.decodeIfPresent(Date.self, forKey: .purchaseDate)

    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
        try container.encode(title, forKey: .title)
try container.encode(purchaseDate, forKey: .purchaseDate)
}
}

//   Purchase+CoreDataProperties.swift

extension Purchase {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Purchase> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Purchase>(entityName: "Purchase")
    } 


    @NSManaged public var id: String?
    @NSManaged public var title: String?
    @NSManaged public var purchaseDate: Date?
}

//CALL

   let decoder = JSONDecoder()

                    decoder.dataDecodingStrategy = .base64
                    let purchases = try decoder.decode([Purchase].self, from: value)

If i remove "purchaseDate" everything works correctly
```

Comment: In json purchaseDate is in string format which is mismatch for your datatype Date in your data model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a general misunderstanding, the error is about `Date` not `Data`

The error occurs because the JSON decoder does not decode ISO8601 dates by default. The default is a `TimeInterval` aka `Double`.

That's what the error message says: *It expects a `Double` but found a `String`*

You have to set the `DateDecodingStrategy` of the decoder to `.iso8601`

```
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
```

And remove the exclamation mark in `try!` to hand over the error

Comment: 'JSONDecoder.DataDecodingStrategy' has no member 'iso8601' @vadian

Comment: Once again Dat**E** not Dat**A**. `purchaseDate` is the ISO8601 representation of date & time, not binary data

Comment: okay. But decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601 it seems an invalid option

Comment: The option is [valid](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonencoder.dateencodingstrategy/2895032-iso8601)

Comment: sorry. it was a compile problem.

Comment: I'm getting this same error @AndreaBozza. Can you say what exactly fixed it for you?

Comment: Ahhhh! Nobody spelled it out, but there are both `.dateDecodingStrategy` and `.dataDecodingStrategy` properties on `JSONDecoder`. This seems like poor naming choices to me.